# Scraping one page with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a long stream of URLs that I need to scrape and extract data, I want to use scrapy for that.

Say I have a Twisted reactor setup and I creating spider

```
runner = CrawlerRunner(scrapy_settings)
d = runner.crawl(spider_cls)
```

Is there a way I can send URLs to spider so it'll process them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`crawl()` method](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html?highlight=crawlerrunner#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerRunner.crawl) can take additional arguments:

```
d = runner.crawl(spider_cls, start_urls=["url"])
```

Comment: Is there a way to reuse the spider? To avoid creating it again when I get new URLs?

Comment: @AlexV this is an interesting question! Could you please create a separate question providing all the necessary details? Thank you!